# Bizarre .Join() behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

For some reason " ".join() in my code seems to be adding extra spaces where there shouldn't be any. Sorry if this is a very noob question but I have no clue despite usually being able to figure stuff like this out.

Code in question (just a snippet but the rest shouldn't be relevant)

```
def translate(stringinput):
    if all(c in string.printable for c in stringinput):
        output = ""
        sent_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
        sentences = sent_detector.tokenize(stringinput.strip())
        for sentence in sentences:
            sentence = shuffle(sentence)
            output = output + " " + sentence_translate(sentence)
        print(output.split())
        " ".join(output.split())
        return output.strip()
    else:
        print("Input does not entirely consist of ASCII Characters. Offending characters were:")
        print([c for c in stringinput if c not in string.printable])

stringinput = "Ulysses, Ulysses - Soaring through all the galaxies. In search of Earth, flying in to the night. Ulysses, Ulysses - Fighting evil and tyranny, with all his power, and with all of his might. Ulysses - no-one else can do the things you do. Ulysses - like a bolt of thunder from the blue. Ulysses - always fighting all the evil forces bringing peace and justice to all."
print(translate(stringinput))
writer(folder / "final.json", dict)
```

The lines in question are

```
print(output.split())
" ".join(output.split())
return output.strip() -> which is then printed out via print(translate(stringinput))
```

The printouts from these two are:

```
['kwmuo', 'kwmuo', 'jhhdd', 'zzazyayb', 'ptictte', 'igbo', 'tkaty', 'puiq.', 'xpaiuc', 'ftucqtze', 'ossjjh', 'ywwuh', 'rpauuqqz', 'fddu', 'pfhqys', 'igbo', 'kwmuo', 'qpousq,', 'zaapyuwq,', 'zqaoys,', 'histje', 'kwmuo', 'uzzaa', 'ptictte', 'eczt', 'rkmwy', 'uzzaa,', 'zaapyuwq,', 'ptictte,', 'xpaiuc,', 'eczt,', 'rssjj', 'kwmuo', 'hydymw', 'mfusq', 'gotsejz', 'igbo', 'mkpwhu', 'mkpwhu', 'os', 'gooss', 'teezc', 'kwmuo', 'dyyww', 'gtokb.', 'xpaiuc', 'cxxppu,', 'uqqzzan', 'igbo', 'gooss', 'kwmuo', 'hdyyyy', 'itfe.', 'uqqlos', 'ptictte', 'igbo', 'zqaoys', 'ywwhuyq', 'zaapyuwq', 'hdyyyy', 'osgjhhy', 'ptictte', 'rpauuqqz']
```

and

```
kwmuo kwmuo jhhdd zzazyayb ptictte igbo tkaty  puiq. xpaiuc ftucqtze ossjjh ywwuh rpauuqqz fddu pfhqys igbo  kwmuo qpousq, zaapyuwq, zqaoys, histje kwmuo uzzaa ptictte eczt rkmwy uzzaa, zaapyuwq, ptictte, xpaiuc, eczt, rssjj  kwmuo hydymw mfusq gotsejz igbo mkpwhu mkpwhu os gooss  teezc kwmuo dyyww gtokb. xpaiuc cxxppu, uqqzzan igbo gooss  kwmuo hdyyyy itfe. uqqlos ptictte igbo zqaoys ywwhuyq zaapyuwq hdyyyy osgjhhy ptictte rpauuqqz
```

For instance, if you look between *tkaty* and *puiq*, both of their array entries clearly have no trailing or leading whitespace, so why does the joined version clearly have two spaces inbetween?? This continues sporadically throughout the output with no obvious pattern. This is reproducible, I have run the code again a bunch of times with the exact same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: `" ".join(output.split())` does not affect anything if you don't capture the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign the output of the `join` method to something, it doesn't work in-place:

```
print(output.split())
" ".join(output.split())
return output.strip()
```

should be

```
print(output.split())
output = " ".join(output.split())
return output.strip()
```

Comment: I am massively retarded. Thank you, tested and works. I will accept the answer once the timer runs out (why is that even a feature??)

Comment: @Arelus to encourage more people answering and maybe get another better approach. And to avoid questions being open and immediately not relevant (usually people seeing a question accepted doesn't bother to go in)

Comment: I see. Either way, this "problem" certainly needs no more answers or approaches, so I accepted it.

Comment: @Arelus note that the final `strip()` is not really necessary as the `split()` does that already for you. So you can just `return ' '.join(output.split())`

Comment: Thanks. It was having an effect earlier but only because the .join wasn't doing anything at all. Honestly efficiency doesn't matter much in this code so I wasn't too cautious about redundant statements/conditions etc (I'm sure if the entire thing was uploaded here it'd be ripped apart) I just wanted it to work.